# How to change one value in each object for an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object as seen below:

```js
const arr = [
{
    content: 'string',
    read: true
},
{
    content: 'string',
    read: false
},
{
    content: 'string',
    read: false
},
]
```

How would I edit the array and make all the `read` properties set to true?

Comment: You need to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Is there any way that I could mutate the same array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.map()`:

```
  arr.map(elem => {
    elem.read = true;
    return elem;
  })
```